# FluentValidation + Ninject: how to set up AbstractValidator for dependency injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ninject, fluentvalidation

I am using FluentValidation and Ninject. I am trying to inject a service into AbstractValidator

```
[Validator(typeof(CompetitionFormModelValidator))]
public class CompetitionFormModel
{

    public string FirstName { get; set; }     

}
```

and for my validation:

```
public class CompetitionFormModelValidator : AbstractValidator<CompetitionFormModel>
{

    IUserService UserService;

    public CompetitionFormModelValidator(IUserService UserService)
    {

        this.UserService= UserService;

        RuleFor(c => c.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage(" ").Length(1, 100);

        Custom(c =>
        {
            //.. try uusing UserService here


            return null;
        });      



    }
}
```

In my global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        var ninjectValidatorFactory = new NinjectValidatorFactory(new StandardKernel());
        ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider(ninjectValidatorFactory));
        DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
        FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(x => x.ValidatorFactory = ninjectValidatorFactory);            

    }
```

In NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        AssemblyScanner.FindValidatorsInAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
.ForEach(match => kernel.Bind(match.InterfaceType)
    .To(match.ValidatorType));

        kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();

    }
```

The project compiles just fine. When I wasn't trying to use DI, validation was working just fine too. Now that I am trying inject IUserService, validation isn't called.

Have I set up the configuration of ninject.web.mvc.fluentvalidation properly ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Application_Start, you new up the `NinjectValidatorFactory` with a new `StandardKernel` instead of using your existing kernel - so the validators you registered on your existing kernel won't be found by the `NinjectValidatorFactory`.

Moving this block of code to a place where you have access to the existing kernel and passing that in should fix the problem.